# How to make post call using headers and body angular 5

Tags: ionic-framework, angular5

Hi Developers I'm new into ionic and angular. Could you please help me?

[image]

[image]

How can I get `itemAry` and how to set in `api.ts` file(post method).[image]

In `api.ts` file now the details are static. How can I get dynamically?

Comment: why need to send body...

Comment: Please edit code and give me more details.

Comment: Without body I can't details

Comment: What is apiKey? is it dynamic or static .. and update more details in your code.. input and output need to be clear

Comment: apikey is rest api url.I stored in configuration file and I used there

Answer (score 0):

```
getOrderDetailsData(obj){
    path:{
    apiKey: this.apiKey
    },
    body:obj
}
```

Comment: Tq Sayed  But it doesn't worked for me. Can please explain in    details.

Comment: obj is the dynamic body you can send from getOrderDetailsData, In function orderdetailData()
define your body and send as a parameter to this.api.getOrderDetailsData(body)